# How can I embed web.config appsetting value in image tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I embed my appsetting key value into image tag. I have my base path in web.config file. as

```
 <appSettings>
     <add key="BasePath" value="/Myproject/"/>
 </appSettings>
```

```html
@model List<Myproject.Models.List>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List";
    var basePath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BasePath"];
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
 <td>
        <video class="videoplay" controls width="150" height="150">
            <source src="basePath + @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.url)" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        </td>
   }     
}
```

I tried to add like above but did not help. I am not sure how to embed appsetting key value. any suggestions, please.

Comment: why you don't want to use <base> tag in layout.cshtml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `DisplayFor` here:

```
<source src="@(basePath + item.url)" type="video/mp4">
```